# Рассчитать паддинги для псевдоэлементов

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

А можете подсказать, как высчитать расстояние для вот этих черточек, выполненных в виде псевдоэлементов, которые я выделила красным? Skills короче Portfolio и поэтому расстояния right и left не подходят для Portfolio. Может быть, это задается с помощью calc? Можете подсказать формулу calc?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.section-title {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #BDAE82;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative;
}


.section-title::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 238px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #BDAE82;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 375px;
}

.section-title::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 238px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #BDAE82;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 375px;
}
```

Comment: Есть возможность приложить стили для `.section-title`?

Comment: Добавила стили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.section-title {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #BDAE82;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section-title > span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.section-title > span::before,
.section-title > span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
}

.section-title > span::before {
  right: 100%;
}

.section-title > span::after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="section-title"><span>Skills</span></h2>

<h2 class="section-title"><span>Portfolio</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно например так.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

h2 {
  color: #752dff;
  position: relative;
}

h2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background: #752dff;
}

h2 span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2><span>First</span></h2>
  <h2><span>Second</span></h2>
  <h2><span>StackOverflow</span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Не думаю, что перекрывать бекграундом разумное решение. И это совсем неуниверсально

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, Вам подойдет подобный вариант. Рассчитать ширину для псевдокласса средствами CSS не самый лучший вариант. К тому же, нужно быть уверенным, что строка будет всегда извезстных размеров.
Попробуйте это:

```css
.section-title {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #BDAE82;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section-title::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background: #BDAE82;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 375px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  flex: 1;
}

.section-title::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background: #BDAE82;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 375px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-title">
  <div class="section-title__content">text1</div>
</div>
<div class="section-title">
  <div class="section-title__content">text2 text2</div>
</div>
```